# jquery Slider with two arrows

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for jquery slider with two arrow.Here is working of [jquery slider with arrow](http://www.israel-diamonds.com/search/diamonds/result.aspx). Is there any way to download it ? thanks

Comment: This worked for me:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551203/changing-jquery-range-slider-images][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551203/changing-jquery-range-slider-images

Comment: This worked for me:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551203/changing-jquery-range-slider-images][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551203/changing-jquery-range-slider-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:
[How to change Jquery UI Slider handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207307/how-to-change-jquery-ui-slider-handle)

or: [Changing Slider handle image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170596/changing-slider-handle-image)

Answer (score 0):

The base Jquery-ui library has this:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range

Just set `range: true,` in you jquery slider options.

Comment: looks like op's link uses the jquery ui slider aswell, they've just set the background of the handle to a custom image.

Comment: that is why I linked him to it >_>