# How to replace the jquery slider handles with my own images

Tags: image, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-slider

I know this question has been asked, but I can not get the solutions to work.  I'm not seeing my images.  The image path is correct. What am I doing wrong?

I've read the solutions to this question:  [Changing slider handle image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170596/changing-slider-handle-image),
[Jquery slider with two arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261820/jquery-slider-with-two-arrows), and
[changing jquery slider images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551203/changing-jquery-range-slider-images).  The third solution seems to be the best, but I'm not sure how to get this to work. I've copied and pasted, but I am unable to get this working.  Here is full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-
 ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js">
 </script>
 <script>
$(window).load(function(){
//Used for slider with two arrows - start
var firstHandleClass = 'first-handle';
var secondHandleClass = 'second-handle';

handle = $('#slider-range A.ui-slider-handle');
handle.removeClass('ui-corner-all');
handle.removeClass('ui-slider-handle');
handle.addClass('handle_');
handle.eq(0).addClass(firstHandleClass);
handle.eq(1).addClass(secondHandleClass);    

});
</script>
    <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
range: true,
values: [5,17]
});
    });
   </script>


  <style type="text/css">

     #slider { margin: 10px; }
.handle_ {
     cursor: default;
     position: absolute;
     top: -0.3em;
     z-index: 2;
  }
.first-handle {
    background: url("images/lefthandle.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-style: none;
    height: 36px;
    margin-left: -9px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 21px;
}
.second-handle {
    background: url("images/righthandle.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-style: none;
    height: 36px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 21px;
}
   </style>

  </head>
  <body style="font-size:62.5%;">

  <div id="slider"></div>


</body> 
</html>
```

[image]

Here is a screenshot.  The images are not displaying.  Anyone?

Thanks.

Comment: I looked at the code in firebug and the new classes `first-handle` ad `second-handle` are not being added.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the selector `'#slider-range a.ui-slider-handle'` doesn't match any elements.  Try replacing it with `'#slider a.ui-slider-handle'` and see if that fixes it, like so:

```
handle = $('#slider A.ui-slider-handle');
handle.removeClass('ui-corner-all');
handle.removeClass('ui-slider-handle');
handle.addClass('handle_');
handle.eq(0).addClass(firstHandleClass);
handle.eq(1).addClass(secondHandleClass);
```